# Error in Converting JSON to a C# Class Model

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to convert JSON string to a class model but always and getting error. I have have check all names and data types are matching but still getting error. My code:

//method model

```
 Public Class ClassModel

    Public No As String
    Public Amt As Integer

End Class
```

//this is .net standard(2.0) class library(vb.net) that is refrenced in c# project and generate result

```
Public Class NumberEntry

 Public Function Result(ClassModel As ClassModel)
    Dim DsResult As New DataSet

    Dim DtStatus As New DataTable

    Try

        DtStatus.Columns.Add("StatusCode")
        DtStatus.Columns.Add("Message")

        Dim row As DataRow = DtStatus.NewRow
        DtStatus.Rows.Add(row)

        Dim dt As New DataTable

        dt.Columns.Add("Number", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add("Amount", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))

        Dim NewAmt As Integer
        NewAmt = RoundOff(AndarBaharModel.Amt)


       
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10 - 1
            Dim NewNo = AndarBaharModel.No & i

            dt.Rows.Add(NewNo, NewAmt / 10, "A")

            If dt.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString = "00" Then
                dt.Rows(i).Item(0) = "100"
            End If
        Next

        Dim dv As New DataView(dt)
        dv.Sort = "Number asc"
        Dim FinalDt As DataTable = dv.ToTable()

        DsResult.Tables.Add(FinalDt)
        DsResult.Tables.Add(DtStatus)

        DtStatus.Rows(0).Item("StatusCode") = 1
        DtStatus.Rows(0).Item("Message") = "No Has Been Successfully Saved"

    Catch ex As Exception
        DtStatus.Rows(0).Item("StatusCode") = 0
        DtStatus.Rows(0).Item("Message") = ex.Message.ToString()
        DsResult.Tables.Add(DtStatus)

        Return DsResult

    Finally
        If DsResult.Tables.Count = 1 Then
            DsResult.Tables(0).TableName = "NumberStatus"
        Else
            DsResult.Tables(0).TableName = "NumberResult"
            DsResult.Tables(1).TableName = "NumberStatus"
        End If

    End Try

    Return DsResult

End Function
```

end sub

// this is c# project where above class library is used

// class model

```
public class NumberResultModel
{
    public List<NumberResult> NumberResult { get; set; }
    public List<NumberStatus> NumberStatus { get; set; }
}

public class NumberResult
{
   public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}


public class NumberStatus
{
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

//converting JSON to class

```
           var ClassResult = new R1Soft_PCL.NumberEntry();
            var model = new ClassModel();

            model.No = "1";
            model.Amt = "50";
            var result = ClassResult.Result(model);



 var Jason= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
 
var JasonString= "{"NumberResult":[
 {"Number":"10","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"11","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"12","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"13","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"14","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"15","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"16","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"17","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"18","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"19","Amount":20,"ID":"A"}],
 "NumberStatus":[
 {"StatusCode":"1","Message":"Andar No Has Been Successfully Saved"}]}""


 var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NumberResultModel>>(Jason);
```

//getting this below error--

```
  One or more errors occurred. (Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) 
  into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[R1Soft_App.Models.NumberResultModel]' 
  because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
  To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized 
  type so that it is a normal .NET type 
  (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can 
  be deserialized from a JSON object. 
  JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
  Path 'NumberResult', line 1, position 16.)
```

Comment: Please provide *actual code* instead of pseudo-code - the place where you've specified the JSON isn't a valid C# string literal. But fundamentally, the problem is that your JSON represents a *single* NumberResultModel, but you're trying to deserialize it to a `List<NumberResultModel>`. Just call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NumberResultModel>` instead and it should be fine.

Comment: You need to do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NumberResultModel>(Jason)`

Comment: As a side-note, the file format is JSON, not Jason - it's an easy mistake to make, but it's worth getting into the habit of referring to the right name.

Comment: I'm not sure how that error message could be much more helpful; it's told you the exact problem in a clear and concise way and suggested 3 different solutions. What problem do you face after you read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously You are trying to deserialize a **json object** to a **json Array**

*What does it means?*

this  `{"KEY":"VALUE"}` is a **json object**. However, `[{"KEY":"VALUE"}]` is a **json array**, because it encircled by `[]`

IF you are trying to deserialize below object

```
var JasonString= "{"NumberResult":[
 {"Number":"10","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"11","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"12","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"13","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"14","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"15","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"16","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"17","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"18","Amount":20,"ID":"A"},
 {"Number":"19","Amount":20,"ID":"A"}],
 "NumberStatus":[
 {"StatusCode":"1","Message":"Andar No Has Been Successfully Saved"}]}""
```

so you need to change

```
var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NumberResultModel>>(Jason);
```

to

```
var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NumberResultModel>(Jason);
```